# Fix One or more validation errors were detected during model generation using dataannotation

Tags: .net, sql, ef-code-first

Iam using Sql 2008 r2 and visual studio 2010 and EF 4.4. And iam getting this error runnning the code longer down. The Code should explain the database relations.

> **One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:** 
>   \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationConstraint: : The number of properties in the >Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.

I want to solve this using dataannotation. What am i doing wroing?

'Offer

```
    Public Class Offer

        <Key(), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)>
        Public Property Offer_ID As Integer
        Public Property Name As String

    End Class
```

'Head

```
Public Class Head

    <Key(), Column(Order:=0), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)>
    Public Property Head_ID As Integer

    <ForeignKey("Offer_ID")>
    Public Property Offer As Offer

    <Key(), Column(Order:=1)>
    Public Property Offer_ID As Integer

    Public Property Name As String


End Class
```

'Line

```
   Public Class Line

        <Key(), Column(Order:=0), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)>
        Public Property Line_ID As Integer

        <ForeignKey("Head_ID")>
        Public Property Head As Head

        <Key(), Column(Order:=1)>
        Public Property Head_ID As Integer

        <ForeignKey("Offer_ID")>
        Public Property Offer As Offer

        <Key(), Column(Order:=2)>
        Public Property Offer_ID As Integer

        Public Property Name As String

   End Class
```

'DbContext

```
    Public Class DatabaseContext
        Inherits DbContext

        Public Sub New(p_ConnectionString As String)
            MyBase.New(p_ConnectionString)
        End Sub

        Public Property Offers As DbSet(Of Offer)
        Public Property Heads As DbSet(Of Head)
        Public Property Lines As DbSet(Of Line)

    End Class
```

'Create a simple example

```
    Private Shared Sub CreateME()

        Dim offer As New Offer
        offer.Name = "Offer1"
        offer.Offer_ID = 1

        Dim head As New Head
        head.Head_ID = 1
        head.Name = "head1"
        head.Offer = offer
        head.Offer_ID = offer.Offer_ID

        Dim line As New Line
        line.Head = head
        line.Head_ID = head.Head_ID
        line.Line_Id = 1
        line.Name = "line1"
        line.Offer = offer
        line.Offer_ID = offer.Offer_ID

        Using context = New DatabaseContext(GetConnectionString())

            context.Offers.Add(offer)
            context.Heads.Add(head)
            context.Lines.Add(line)
            context.SaveChanges()
        End Using

    End Sub
```

**So the question is can i solve this using data annotation?**

Do i have to use the modelbuilder explained in here: 
[How to fix: The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754842/how-to-fix-the-number-of-properties-in-the-dependent-and-principal-roles-in-a-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I think your database relations would like this, am I correct?

[image: Database Relations]

- `Offers` has a simple primary key of `Offer_ID`
- `Heads` has a composite primary key of `Head_ID` and `Offer_ID`
- `Heads` has a foreign key to `Offers`
- `Lines` has a composite primary key of `Line_ID`, `Head_ID` and `Offer_ID`
- `Lines` has a foreign key to `Heads`

Assuming I am correct in my reading of your question...

---

You are nearly perfect with your code.  The only thing is the `Line` class.  Here you are specifying:

```
<ForeignKey("Head_ID")>
Public Property Head As Head
```

but instead you need:

```
<ForeignKey("Head_ID, Offer_ID")>
Public Property Head As Head
```

All down to a tricky comma-separated string!

The reason is that the primary key on Heads is a composite so you must specify all the columns to make the relationship correct.

Comment: Thanks, great answer even with a picture. I didnt now you could have two foreignkeys in one annotation. There are so few more complicated database examples using data annotation one the web- I think you could also do this:

    Public Property Head As Head

    <Key(), ForeignKey("Head"), Column(Order:=1)>
    Public Property Head_ID As Integer

    <Key(), ForeignKey("Head"), Column(Order:=2)>
    Public Property Offer_ID As Integer

Answer (score 1):

Your Head class has a foreign key comprising of Head_Id and and Offer Id.  Your Line class needs to reference the Head via a foreign key comprised of Head Id and Offer Id.

You can use data annotations and the Column Order syntax.  You should be able to find the exact syntax on MSDN.