# Delete elements of nested collections in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, one-to-many, composite-primary-key, composite-key

I am using Entity Framework to store objects of the following entity classes:

```
public class Library
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private ICollection<Book> _books;
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books => _books ?? (_books = new List<Book>());
}

public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int LibraryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Library Library { get; set; }

    private ICollection<Page> _pages;
    public virtual ICollection<Page> Pages => _pages ?? (_pages = new List<Page>());
}

public class Page
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to remove individual pages and books from the corresponding collections, so I do the following configuration with the fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Library>()
    .HasMany(library => library.Books)
    .WithOptional()
    .HasForeignKey(book => book.LibraryId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
    .HasKey(book => new { book.Id, book.LibraryId })
    .Property(book => book.Id)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
    .HasMany(book => book.Pages)
    .WithOptional()
    .HasForeignKey(page => page.BookId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Page>()
    .HasKey(page => new { page.Id, page.BookId })
    .Property(page => page.Id)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

I create composite keys for `Book` and `Page` and set up the one-to-many relationships.

When I try to create a migration I get the following error:

`Book_Pages_Source_Book_Pages_Target: : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.`

I suspect the error is on the foreign key of `Page`, which should probably include `LibraryId`, since it is part of the PK of `Book`... How should I fix the configuration?

Comment: Perhaps your FK on page is wrong as it references only a part of `Book`'s PK? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11755058/7034621

Comment: There are many flaws in this model. First, the `Identity` columns are already unique, so there is absolutely no need to create composite PKs. Second, both the `.WithOptional()` mappings are wrong - the FKs are `int`, hence **required**, and also the corresponding navigation properties are not mapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As orhtej2 points out in the comment above the FK relationship on `Page` missed  `LibraryId`, since this value also part of `Book`'s PK. I have moved away from the fluent API and used data annotations instead. The following entity classes are doing what I needed:

```
public class Library
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private ICollection<Book> _books;
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books => _books ?? (_books = new List<Book>());
}       

public class Book
{   
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("Library")]
    public int LibraryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Library Library { get; set; }

    private ICollection<Page> _pages;
    public virtual ICollection<Page> Pages => _pages ?? (_pages = new List<Page>());
}

public class Page
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("Book")]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2), ForeignKey("Book")]
    public int LibraryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

The composite keys in `Book` and `Page` are needed to make sure that when I, for example, remove an item from the `Pages` collection of one book, not only is the relationship between `Page` and `Book` deleted, but also the record that stores the page is actually deleted from the database (as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17726414/5689927)).