# Inserting / saving entity with nested children entities with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here are the classes:

```
public class Parent 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<Child> Childs { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<ParentLog> Logs { get; set; }
}

public class ParentLog 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public DateTime On { get; set; }
     public string Note { get; set; }
     public int ParentId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Child 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int ParentId { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<ChildLog> Logs { get; set; }
}

public class ChildLog 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public DateTime On { get; set; }
     public string Note { get; set; }
     public int ChildId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

In `DbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().HasMany(a => a.Childs);
     modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().HasMany(a => a.Logs);
     modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().HasMany(a => a.Logs);
}
```

The idea is for log entries for both Parent and Child be saved also, when Parent and Child is saved. This works.

Codes for saving:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
foreach (var a in parents)
{
     a.Logs = new List<ParentLog>();
     a.Logs.Add(new ParentLog
     {
          On = now,
          Note = "Created",
          Name = a.Name
     });

     foreach(var b in a.Childs)
     {
         b.Logs = new List<ChildLog>();
         b.Logs.Add(new ChildLog
         {
              On = now,
              Note = "Created",
              Name = b.Name,
              ParentId = b.ParentId //not needed with the Accepted Answer.
          });
     }
}

int recordsAffected = new ParentRepository().SaveParents(parents);
```

```
public int SaveParents(List<Parent> items)
{
     foreach(var item in items)
     {
          _db.Parents.Add(item);
     }

     return _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The issue I'm encountering is with the `ChildLog.ParentId`. It doesn't have the value of the expected value, which is coming from `Child.ParentId` I suppose.

My question, how to resolve it?

Comment: Since `ChildLog` does not have any direct relation with entity `Parent`, just saving a change log from `Child` entity... you must pass the `Child.ParentId` property value to the `ChildLog.ParentId` property.

Comment: Luis, I tried that too, the value saved for ChildLog.ParentId is still 0 ,while for ChildLog.ChildId, it's the actual Child.Id.

Comment: You don't show the saving code you have problems with.

Comment: Gert Arnold, I just added the codes for saving.

Comment: Doesn't show the most essential part: are all of these objects new? I guess they are, so `ParentId` simply doesn't have its generated value yet. You can only assign them after saving.

Comment: Yes. They're all new, even Parents and Childs which were passed from ajax call and already shaped to List<Parent> parents. Only ChildLog.ParentId is not getting the generated value, while ParentLog.ParentId is getting it. Included the SaveParents method.

Comment: @LesterS You just confirmed my point, you are trying to save all entities at once but, since there is not relation between Parent and ChildLog, the `ChildLog.ParentId` is never updated with the generated ID. You either define a relation between the entities to allow EF handle the update or you create/update the `ChildLog.ParentId` in a second transaction.

Comment: Luis, I'm thinking EF can handle that in a single SaveChanges. In that case I'll do a 2nd SaveChanges since having a Parent.ChildLog does not make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out EF can handle it in one SaveChanges(). Though, I needed to define the relationships explicitly.

Here are the classes that have been updated:

```
public class Child 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int ParentId { get; set; }
     public IEnumerable<ChildLog> Logs { get; set; }
     //Added
     public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

public class ChildLog 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public DateTime On { get; set; }
     public string Note { get; set; }
     public int ChildId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int ParentId { get; set; }
     //Added
     public Child Child { get; set; }
}
```

and here's the updated OnModelCreating method in DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     var parent = modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>();
     parent.HasKey(a => a.Id);
     parent.Property(a => a.ParentId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
     parent.HasMany(a => a.Logs); //ParentLog

     var child = modelBuilder.Entity<Child>();
     child.HasKey(a => new { a.Id, a.ParentId });
     child.Property(a => a.ChildId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
     child.HasRequired(a => a.Parent).WithMany(a => a.Childs).HasForeignKey(a => a.ParentId);

     var childLog = modelBuilder.Entity<ChildLog>();
     childLog.HasKey(a => new { a.Id, a.ChildId, a.ParentId });
     childLog.Property(a => a.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
     childLog.HasRequired(a => a.Child).WithMany(a => a.Logs).HasForeignKey(a => new { a.ChildId, a.ParentId });
}
```

This helps me with this -> [How to fix: The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754842/how-to-fix-the-number-of-properties-in-the-dependent-and-principal-roles-in-a-r)

So much trouble for that little but crucial thing.

Answer (score 0):

Add a navigation property to the Child model, ChildLog >Child.

Then you'll be able to access the ParentId via the Child.

Further reading - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships